# Regex not working with Grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, wget

im trying to print the content of a html table cell.

i thought the easiest way to do this was with grep,
but for some reason the regex works on regexr.com but not within Grep.

Maybe something with escaping? i tried escaping al the smaller and larger than <> symbols.

This is the code i'm using

```
wget -q -O login.html --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'username=sssss&password=fffff' http://ffffff/login

wget -q -O page.html --load-cookies cookies.txt http://ffffff/somepage |grep -P '(?<=<tr><td class=list2>www</td><td class=list2 align=center>A</td><td class=list2 >)(.*?)(?=</td><td class=list2 align=center><input type=checkbox name=arecs5)' |recode html...ascii
```

Can anybody help me please? I'm from the netherlands so sorry for my english.

i aslo tried adding the -c option and it printed 0

EDIT:

Added my full code, i found 1 mistake. i didn't have the -O parameter to output the page's html. but it still doesnt work. it prints nothing

Comment: Take care that regex and html are not good friends!

Comment: i've read that yes, but i don't care about security since its not like the page i'm trying to wget is gonna hack me.. or is that not what you mean?

Comment: I'd say that parsing html with regex is really hard, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239

Comment: well, that's ok. i'm only using this part, it's a very simple task, it just doesn't work. haha.

Comment: Regexes work fine until they don't because the HTML changes.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes longer explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it works.
I added -qO- to wget, i don't know why but when adding a - after the -O it works.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional `grep` doesn't support lookarounds the way you're using it.

Try using `grep -P (PCRE)`:

```
grep -P 'pattern' file
```

Comment: I tried adding P but still nothing,
my whole line actually is wget --load-cookies cookies.txt url |grep -P 'regex'|recode html...ascii
maybe that changes something? maybe i have to select the file path instead of using wget pipelined directly?

Comment: You can do it as: `wget --load-cookies cookies.txt url | grep "$pattern"` and make sure `$pattern` is set earlier.

Comment: tried that too, do i have to use the double quotes around $PATTERN ?
when i don't add them it print Grep: missing ')' or something

Comment: Yes definitely use double quotes as I wrote in my comments. Shell wont expand your variable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) or [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) that supports natively PCRE.